# Why gets method is not shown in autocomplete?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and ReSharper for my C programs but I can not make gets method work in this IDE. Why is this method not shown in autocomplete list?

[image: 1st]

[image]

Comment: The `gets` function have been deprecated since the C99 standard, and was removed in the C11 standard. It's [a dangerous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used), do not use it!

Comment: Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: thank you for the answer...

Comment: C does not support _methods_. `gets` was a _function_.

Comment: Please post text rather than images. They may not be visible to all users -- or any searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets):.

The gets() function does not perform bounds checking, therefore this function is extremely vulnerable to buffer-overflow attacks. It cannot be used safely (unless the program runs in an environment which restricts what can appear on stdin). For this reason, **the function has been deprecated in the third corrigendum to the C99 standard and removed altogether in the C11 standard**. fgets() and gets_s() are the recommended replacements.
**Never use gets().**

Comment: cppreference is not **the** C documentation. That would be the standard as ther only official reference.